# How does JOSS (Java client for OpenStack Swift) determine what proxy servers to use?

Tags: java, client, storage, openstack, openstack-swift

Can we force JOSS to use special proxy servers (in local DC or certain proxy server)? Will it use only one or several proxy servers to contact?